# Select last two years on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select last 2 years from weeks (not depending on today's date), but my table contains multiple entries for the same week like this (example) :

```
week      product   release
-------|---------|---------
11        xx        zz
11        ab        cd
12        yy        ff
12        pp        jj
... and so on until two years equivalent (104 weeks)
```

Knowing that I won't have one row for each week, I can't use `LIMIT 104`.

How can I do this query? I'm using MySQL.

I've tried this but it returns one row for each week...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM t 
 WHERE t.week = ANY (
                SELECT t.week 
                  FROM t) 
 LIMIT 0, 104;
```

Comment: looks like IN OPERATOR

Comment: I think a distinct in the subquery part will work

Comment: week 11 can repeat for other year also. ie week 11 will be there is first year and second year.

Comment: You need to have the year info to get the weeks for that specific years

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM t 
 WHERE t.week IN (
              SELECT distinct week 
                FROM t) 
 LIMIT 0,104
```

Comment: I've tried limit in the subquery but I get the error "your version of MySQL does not support limit in subquery... I can't upgrade mysql because it's on another server.

Comment: But the distinct will return only ONE row for each week, while I want all the rows there are in the table for each week..

Comment: you are right ... semantic fault from me ... do you have the possibility to run a query and use its processed result in another one?

Comment: yeah. like if you are in a C application, you could create a 2nd query for the `distinkt week's`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you well:

```
SELECT * FROM t 
WHERE week >= (SELECT MAX(week) FROM t) - 104
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this buddy.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE t.week>0 and (not t.week>104);
```